# Изменение масштаба для части картинки в PhotoShop

Tags: photoshop

Как можно изменить масштаб картинки, потянув например за верхний правый угол?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно подробнее?

Comment: Ну холст больше чем сама картинка, окей, а что нажимать нужно для такого растягивания? Для обычного ctrl+t работает

Comment: безрезультатно, увеличил холст, ничего не появилось

Comment: ctrl+t, затем зажать альт и потянуть за угол

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не соответствует тематике сайта

Answer (score 2):

Требуемая опция находится по пути: Редактирование->Трансформирование->Искажение